# How to setup view hierarchy for iPad application with Widescreen 16:9 airplay output

Tags: ipad, uiviewcontroller, uiwindow, airplay, widescreen

I want to create an iPad app that besides the normal ipad screen (4:3) uses a second UIScreen containing a UIWindow in 16:9 widescreen format if a second screen is attached. 
I use AppleTV for the connection.

I do not just want to mirror the ipad screen to the TV, because then it is just a 4:3 picture - i want to make it use the whole 16:9 widescreen.

So i started and got the second UIScreen set up and the window is now showing in widescreen format with green background on the TV.

```
//Check for Second Screen and if available, make a second UIWindow and put it on the      second screen
NSArray* connectedScreens = [UIScreen screens];
NSInteger numberOfScreens = [[UIScreen screens]count];
NSLog(@"Number of screens connected: %d",numberOfScreens);

if (numberOfScreens > 1) {
    //we have a second screen connected, display an extra window on the second screen
    UIScreen* secondScreen = [connectedScreens lastObject];
    UIWindow* secondWindow = [[UIWindow alloc]initWithFrame:secondScreen.bounds];
    secondWindow.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    [secondWindow setScreen: secondScreen];
    [secondWindow makeKeyAndVisible];
    self.tvWindow = secondWindow;
}
```

so far so good.

But now i am not sure how to setup the navigation / view hierarchy.

I want to show the same data on both UIScreens (ipad + TV),
just optimized for the different screen dimensions.

As i have exactly the same data that should be displayed and i don't want to have different instances of similar viewControllers floating around i thought i could use two xib files per ViewController, one for the 4:3 ipad view put into the 'view' property of the viewController and one xib for the 16:9 widescreen tv, put into the ‘tvView' property of the same viewController.

The ipad UIWindow has a UINavigationController rotating the different UIViewControllers.

So if i push a ViewController onto the ipad Window's Navigationcontroller, i could add the corresponding tvView from the TV-xib to the UIWindow of the TV Screen.

Am i on the right path here?
How would you do this?

a little sketch:
[image: view hierarchy sketch]
:)

Answer (score 0):

That sounds about right. If you’re allowing user interaction with your navigation controller, you’ll have to register as the controller’s `delegate` so you can keep track of what’s happening to your navigation stack on the iPad and swap out your TV views accordingly.